# How to sniff all ARP traffic on a WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, sniffing, arp

I would like to know if it's possible to sniff all ARP traffic (even if I am not the intender destination) on a WiFi network. I've tried on Wireshark and Scapy neither works.

Thank you.

Comment: Have You tried `arp` filter in Wireshark ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus yes, I did. The problem as Spiff says is that ARP responses are unicast, so I think my OS or my NIC just ignore it because I'm not the destination.

Comment: OK, Anyways you got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single AP network, you should be able to sniff it all from the AP. For example, if you're running a Linux router firmware distro such as LEDE on your AP, you could ssh into your router and run tcpdump there.

ARP replies are unicast, and modern WPA2 encryption makes it very difficult to try to sniff and decrypt everyone's unicast traffic. If you have the ability to downgrade your wireless network's security to WEP or no security while you troubleshoot your ARP problem, then you could sniff from any wireless device connected to the network.

Comment: Unlikely I can't access the router. Anyway, I just found a valid solution for small networks, forging the MAC of each client connected gives me the ability to receive and analyze ARP packets whose destination is the forge MAC. In my case, this a good solution to this issue, but in big networks it is not feasible. Thank you for your answer @Spiff :)